# Valores não serializam no retorno em REST com Jersey

Tags: java, restful, jersey

Bom dia pessoal,
sou novo por aqui e iniciante também com Java e estou tendo um problema com a serialização de um objeto e já não sei mais o que fazer.

Estou dando, pelo menos tentando, dar manutenção em um codigo aqui na empresa, tenho uma classe abaixo e alguns atributos não estão sendo serializado, como o id, tentei criar outros atributos como o `idTipoSituacao`, `codigoIdentificador` e `testeCodigoIdentificado` mas eles também não retornam na API REST, tentei trocar o valor de um atributo que já estava sendo enviado/Serializado como o `codSituacao` pelo o valor do id que preciso pegar no Angular que esta no FrontEnd e ele foi tranquilo. Portando não sei se algum lugar tem algum mapeamento pra essa class, e se tem já olhei em todo canto e não achei, se tiverem alguma sugestão de onde procurar agradeço. as anotações que estão no atributo não as entendo ainda muito bem mas pelo que andei pesquisando não são elas que ignoram um atributo na serialização, tentei deixar sem anotação no atributo também e nada muda, o atributo continua não aparecendo.

```
@JsonRootName("tsdSituacaoDTO")
@JsonInclude
@XmlRootElement(name = "tsdSituacaoDTO")
public class TsdTipoSituacaoDTO extends SisprogModelDTO implements InterfaceDTO<TsdTipoSituacao> {

@Id
@SerializedName(value = "id")
private Integer id;

@JsonProperty("idTipoSituacao")
private Integer idTipoSituacao;

@JsonProperty("codigoIdentificado")
private Integer codigoIdentificador;

@SerializedName(value = "testeCodigoIdentificado")
private Integer testeCodigoIdentificado;

@Size(max = 20)
@JsonProperty("codSituacao")
private String codSituacao;

@Size(max = 50)
@JsonProperty("descricao")
private String descricao;

@JsonProperty("bloquear")
private Boolean bloquear;

@Size(max = 20)
@JsonProperty("corSituacao")
private String corSituacao;

@JsonProperty("caracteristica")
private Short caracteristica;

@JsonProperty("modSituacao")
private Integer modSituacao;

@JsonProperty("tipoControle")
private Integer tipoControle;

@JsonProperty("tsdTipoSituacaoMotivoList")
private List<TsdTipoSituacaoMotivoDTO> tsdTipoSituacaoMotivoList;
```

A bairo é o Resource

```
@Stateless
@Path("tsd/cadastros/tsddto")
public class TsdDTOResource {

// Verificar codigo do tsd
private final static String COD_MENU = "105001";
private final static String ENTITY = "Tsd";

@Context
private MessageBodyWriter<Tsd> context;
private TsdFacadeLocal tsdFacade;
private Gson gson;
private Type typeMap;

public TsdDTOResource() {
    try {
        gson = new Gson();
        typeMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        tsdFacade = (TsdFacadeLocal) ServiceLocator.buscarEJB(ENTITY);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TsdDTOResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new GenericException("Erro ao inicializar o TSD!", ex);
    }
}


@GET
//@SecurityCheck(CodMenu = COD_MENU, Entity = ENTITY, Operacao = SisgerOperacaoEnum.CONSULTAR) <-- Comentei pra poder testar sem entrar em todo sistema
//@Interceptors(SecurityCheckInterceptor.class) <-- Comentei pra poder testar sem entrar em todo sistema
@Path("find/{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public TsdDTO find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    TsdDTO tsd = tsdFacade.findDTO(id);
    return tsd;
}
```

Detalhe, quando depuro o código nesse ponto acima quando o retorno do EJB vem com o objeto os valores estão todos lá certinho. algo esta acontecendo desse return ali até chegar na tela. Tanto quando retorna XML quanto JSON ta do mesmo jeito.

Pelo que vi no POM.XML esta usando a seguinte dependencia do Jersey

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
   <version>2.26</version>
 </dependency>
```

Fora isso não achei nenhuma classe com anotação @Provider que estava pesquisado que pudesse esta sendo interceptada pelo Jersey pra mapear a conversão.

Abaixo é o resultado que esta sendo gerado quando o recurso é consumido

```
<tsdTipoSituacao>
  <bloquear>false</bloquear>
  <caracteristica>11</caracteristica>
  <codSituacao>24</codSituacao>
  <corSituacao/>
  <descricao>Tipo Situação Teste 2 Sisprog</descricao>
  <modSituacao>1</modSituacao>
</tsdTipoSituacao>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o atributo de uma classe seja serializado, este deverá possuir a anotação **@JsonProperty** **OU** possuir a função de acesso **get**, exemplo **getId**.

**OBS:**

1. Quando o nome do atributo a ser serializado for diferente da função de acesso ao atributo da classe, pode-se utilizar a anotação junto ao **get**. Exemplo:

> ```
> @JsonProperty("identificador")
> public Integer getId(){
>     return id;
> }
> ```

2. Já quando a função de acesso possuir o mesmo nome do atributo a ser serializado, não é necessário informar a anotação (nem no atributo, nem no **get**). Exemplo:

> ```
> @JsonProperty("id") //ANOTAÇÃO DESNECESSÁRIA
> public Integer getId(){
>     return id;
> }
> ```

Espero ter esclarecido.

Answer (score 0):

consegui fazer o atributo ser serializado.
acredito que era a falta do metodo setId(), não tinha percebido que estava sem.

preciso somente entender agora se realmente precisa dessa anotação `@JsonProperty` com o nome do atributo, pois sem ela não está aparecendo no resultado.

Obrigado